# How can i check for null using a ternary operator in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
  const myuser = userList.filter(itm => itm.user.Id == Id)
  const email = myuser.length > 0 ? myuser[0].user.email : "";
```

The issue is that user can be null and the line itm.user.Id will fail

How can i use a null check as a ternary operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). So this won't fail if you use
`itm?.user?.Id == Id`.

Just make sure to check that myuser actually has a value afterwards.